# GitHub Pages でページ遷移をするとfile not foundになる

Tags: javascript, github-pages

あるチュートリアルを参考にしてWeb siteを作りました。
GitHubにファィルをpushして、webで閲覧できるようにしてあります。
サイトは https://gouehara.github.io/notes-app/ です。

index.htmlのページは閲覧できますが、リンク先の別サイト、つまり、JavaScriptの`Location.assign()` メソッドを使用して create note ボタンをクリックすると https://gouehara.github.io/edit.html#.... に遷移するはずですが、エラーメッセージがでてきます。

live-serverを使用したローカルホストでの閲覧時はうまく遷移します。
なぜGitHubではうまく遷移しないのですか?
ちなみにエラーメッセージは "make sure that the filename case matches the URL" です。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`/edit.html` という形式でファイルを指定した場合、 `edit.html` はその URL のルート直下、つまり https://gouehara.github.io/edit.html に配置されていることになります。しかし、実際には `edit.html` は 
https://gouehara.github.io/notes-app/edit.html に配置されているため、質問文に提示されたような「ファイルがその場所に存在しない」という旨のエラーが発生します。

ルート相対パスで指定するのであれば、 `/notes-app/edit.html` とパスを修正することで、質問者さんの問題は解決するかと思います。